# Openshift oc new-app command getsockopt: connection refused error

Tags: docker, openshift

I am running a RHEL VM with a Docker registry and Openshift Origin image:

```
[root@mtl-vm375 ~]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                          NAMES
e43274649d1d        registry:2          "/bin/registry /etc/d"   13 minutes ago      Up 13 minutes       0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
d819059266fa        openshift/origin    "/usr/bin/openshift s"   29 hours ago        Up 7 hours                                                         origin
```

I can successfully pull from the VM itself via  docker pull localhost:5000/cowsay-dockerfile:2.0

However, inside the Origin container, the equivalent command with new-app fails:

```
[root@mtl-vm375 origin]# oc new-app cowsay-dockerfile:2.0
error: can't look up Docker image "cowsay-dockerfile:2.0": Internal error occurred: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp 10.230.22.20:443: getsockopt: connection refused
error: no match for "cowsay-dockerfile:2.0"
```

I have tried various parameters to new-app, with and without the 2.0 tag, and also as below (using an insecure registry to get things started):

```
[root@mtl-vm375 origin]# oc new-app http://mtl-vm375:5000/cowsay-dockerfile
error: unable to load template file "http://mtl-vm375:5000/cowsay-dockerfile": unable to read URL "http://mtl-vm375:5000/cowsay-dockerfile", server reported 404 404 Not Found
error: no match for "http://mtl-vm375:5000/cowsay-dockerfile"
```

I feel like I must be close to getting the image into Openshift Origin but need someone's magic touch to know what is missing.

Version information:
    [root@mtl-vm375 origin]# oc version
    oc v1.1.5-52-gd58f979
    kubernetes v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5

and

```
[root@mtl-vm375 ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version: docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version:
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "--docker-image" argument; something like the following:

```
oc new-app --docker-image=mtl-vm375:5000/cowsay-dockerfile
```

Do "oc help new-app" to see more options and for other trouble-shooting commands.